# Jenkins SVN credentials for all new jobs

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am trying to automate svn credentials for all new jobs (created from outside Jenkins UI). I know that there are solutions regarding Credentials plugin by just selecting the credentials from the dropdown, but this is different:

I have a Tomcat web app that creates a jenkins job that starts with a svn checkout. The problem is that, even though the scm svn credentials are passed to the job, it still expects me to manually select the Credentials from the dropdown list.

Is there any plugin/way to set the SVN credentials by default for any new job?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

EDIT: If you just want to have a default credentials for a job, use pipeline plugin and just assign it the "ID" that you gave it to the credential.

Create the credentialId parameter, give it a default value (the id of the credentials).

In your groovy script do:

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: "${credentialId}" ..........//The rest
```

You can simplify your process, do this:

**Option 2**: if you want to do that as a dynamic parameter:

Step #1
Create a credentials and give it an ID, for example:

In this case "devops_dev"

[image]

Step #2
So, form Tomcat or whatever you would use, pass "devops_dev" to the job as parameter.

Step #3
In the job you SHOULD be doing pipeline plugin (the most popular in this moment and the "to be")

Step #4
In your SVN checkout you can do something like:

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: "${credentialId}", depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: 'project', remote: "${svn}"]], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
```

Note that your job it has to be a parameter called "credentialId", note that there is ${credentialId} as parameter which in this case it is sent from tomcat.